# Query on existing items from Datastore return undefined in AWS

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, react-native, aws-amplify

I have been experiencing some unusual behavior from AWS recently with some queries suddenly returning undefined when they returned data before. Moreover the data is there indeed when checking the content section in amplify studio. I'm unable to figure out why this is happening.

Here's a sample of the code

```
  useEffect(() => {
    DataStore.query(Lands, (l) => [
      l.available.eq(false),
      l._deleted.eq(null),
    ]).then(setLands);
    console.log("lands = ", lands);
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to print a variable called `lands` but you have not defined it anywhere in the shared script. Should you be printing another variable?

Comment: come on, you should know the states are all declared otherwise useEffect wouldn't even work too since it has to be imported